#  Winter Bash 2020: The return of the unicorn

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, unicorns, winter-bash-2020, easter-eggs

A long time ago in a galaxy far, far away...

Yaakov had to single-handedly save a Winter Event. With so little time and so little budget, he reused the previous year's assets and managed to save the day once again.

In doing so, our little loyal subject reused an Easter egg from the previous year too, and started a little hunt that probably only a single pony would notice. Many animals had that pony to meet, until they found a single unicorn waiting...

A year has passed from that day, and while the chicken moved on and became an actress in [YouTube meme videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ) the unicorn is still there, waiting...

The pony now is reasonably confused. What is all of this about? Who is the unicorn waiting for? Will the princess of Friendship finally visit us during the winter season?

[image: Stay tuned...]

Now two equines are waiting under the falling snow... A unicorn and a derpy gray pony.

Comment: I wanted the Chicken to return...

Comment: So, we have to find An unicorn and a derpy gray pony?

Comment: @SonictheK-DayHedgehog https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/chicken

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because with the closure of Winter Bash 2020 it no longer need to be open but still has historical value.

Answer (score 5):

*A little time after,the two new friends were running in the snow, happily jumping over those punny confused humans that were looking at them with surprised faces. A dinosaur joined them for a little, but he wasn't used to the cold winter... and so he quickly went back to jumping cactus in the desert.

Time passed, and evening came. The gray pony had to return to their mail-delivery work.

"Can we play again tomorrow?", they asked. "Sure" replied the unicorn "but I wont remember you."

"Why not?"  asked the pony "Did I do something to make you angry?".
"An evil ---dev--- wizard put a curse on me. You will have to find a way and break the curse. Unlock my powers and we will be able to play forever".

.... And so a new quest had started for the gray pony.*

[image]

---

So, apparently there are actually two ways to play the Hat Dash game:

- the regular intended mode: just wear one of the mask hats on any site. After a little wait you shall receive a notification that you earned the privilege to play the game. From that point on, the game button should be on the Bash site

[image]

- the "Easter Egg" way. Just input the Konami code on the site (up up down down left right left right B A [Return]). This unlocks the game but only until you change page. Apparently this was made so that people who don't log on the site can play too. Why someone who doesn't have an account should be on the Bash site and think to use the Konami code there I don't know.

There is a caveat though:Catija confirmed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358044/where-can-i-report-scoring-bugs?noredirect=1#comment1195980_358044) my initial fear.

> @SPArcheon If you haven't unlocked the game through the hat, scores aren't counted - there's a note that says exactly that so that players using the code understand their scores aren't being saved. The code is actually there so that anyone can play, including people who aren't logged in. -

While all the scores, including those got BEFORE unlocking the game through the hat ***are indeed recorded***, the leaderboard simply ignores them.

***Therefore, I strongly suggest that if you are actually interested in trying to climb the leaderboard, you should not lose your time with the Easter Egg Konami code unlocked version but instead unlock the permanent version of the game and only play that***

As a bonus, if you really wish to see the code doing something, try it AFTER you unlocked the game either way. Inputing the code a second time will get you a nice Troll video. While we are at it, the same will happen with every "secret" url you may remember from last year, so don't try unless you want to increase Yaakov special [troll counter](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/117306?m=56448470#56448470) (sorry, Yaakov, your secret was never safe with me :P).

......
At least all url but one.
The one that just brings you to a "Stay Tuned..."  message. If that one means something only time will tell. For now, Yaakov was quite good at avoiding a clear reply :P

> [@Derpy stay tuned itself is not a clue to anything other than the simple meaning of the sentence. can't say anything though for any hidden characters that may or may not be returned as well.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56448429#56448429)

> [@Νеvеrꭑoꭇе good things come to those who wait](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8659346#8659346)

**UPDATE FOR HISTORICAL RECORD:**
At the time of posting this answer the url "/unicorn" was indeed part of a yet-to-be-implemented feature, therefore Yaakov had it just return a placeholder message. Later, that same url was modified and became part of a "quest" to get the Unicorn Defender hat (reference [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358638/can-you-help-a-poor-unicorn-to-find-its-way-back-home))

Comment: What's the secret URL that brings you to the "Stay Tuned..." message?

Comment: @kylejrp https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/unicorn

Comment: Huh? https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/hat

Comment: @ppwater that is an endpoint used to retrieve hat data. It returns 404 when an invalid ID is provided... or no ID at all like in your case.