# Hat Dash Strategy and Mechanics ‍♂️

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, unicorns, winter-bash-2020, hat-dash

[image: The colorful Hat Dash pony with dazed eyes from crashing into a pile of hats]

## Accessing Hat Dash

The Hat Dash game can be accessed two ways:

> To earn the privilege to play the game, wear one of the mask hats on any site. After some time, you should receive a Winter Bash notification that you have earned the privilege to play the game.

> If you don't have the privilege yet, you can input the [Konami Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konami_Code) on the [Winter Bash homepage](https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/) by pressing the following sequence of keys: <kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd><kbd>←</kbd><kbd>→</kbd><kbd>←</kbd><kbd>→</kbd><kbd>B</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>. Your scores will be recorded, but they will not be displayed on the Hat Dash leaderboard.

## Controls

To jump, press <kbd>space</kbd> or <kbd>↑</kbd>. If your device has touch controls, you can press the touchscreen to jump.

To duck, press <kbd>↓</kbd>. This reduces the size of your unicorn. If you duck while jumping, you will drop faster than normal.

## Leaderboard

The [leaderboard](https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/hat-dash/leaderboard) is cached for up to 5 minutes and shows the following stats:

- Overall Stats

  - Top Scores
  - Most Time Spent Playing
- Today's Stats

  - Top Scores
  - Most Time Spent Playing

The leaderboard has anti cheat measures and cheated scores will be purged.

## Strategy and Mechanics

Post your tips for getting legitimate high scores on the leaderboard or for understanding the mechanics as an answer below!

If you have discovered any methods to cheat at the game, please post them in [Do you see a way to cheat at Hat Dash?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/358111/703623) instead.

Comment: What... what is this?

Comment: My post or the game? My post is an attempt to get everyone working together to figure out how to get high scores on the leaderboard. The game? It's beautiful 

Comment: Would someone be up for making a visualization of the collision boxes of the unicorn? In the code, they are `[new t(5,42,19,4), new t(18,20,10,23), new t(28,19,35,27), new t(49,8,10,11), new t(56,2,7,6), new t(58,8,12,8), new t(65,4,6,4), new t(71,0,4,4), ]`, which I'm assuming are `(xPos, yPos, width, height)`.

Comment: You may also want to copy from my post [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357976/winter-bash-2020-the-return-of-the-unicorn/357978#357978) a quite important info that you forgot....

Comment: @SPArcheon which part? The hidden page? What's the URL? I wasn't around for the last bash

Comment: Nope, not that, probably not relevant for the game. The part about the scores got from playing the game without using the "standard" unlock method not being included in leaderboard stats. If someone plays using the code, their score is VOID. Not a big issue, but may annoy people who want to climb the leaderboard.... and therefore the ones looking for strategies in this post. Better warn them, the game isn't that clear.

Comment: I've got that mentioned on the unlock method spoiler: "Your scores will be recorded, but they will not be displayed on the Hat Dash leaderboard."

Comment: I'm looking for legitimate strategies for getting high scores, not ways to cheat at the game

Comment: Was the second method disabled? It doesn't work for me.

Comment: Oops, I was missing a key at the end for the code, it should be working now.

Answer (score 11):

## Multiple Obstacles at High Speeds

When the speed gets high enough, obstacles will start coming very quickly. A common way to end the game is when you jump over one obstacle, but you hit the next obstacle before landing.

You can avoid this by jumping really early with the goal of landing just after the obstacle. This can be tricky though, as if the unicorn's tail touches an obstacle, you lose.

You can also avoid this by pressing <kbd>↓</kbd> partway through a jump. You will fall very quickly and can jump again right after touching the ground. Note that you can't jump while the ducking, so you'll want to quickly release <kbd>↓</kbd> after touching the ground.

Answer (score 6):

## Touchscreen Device makes Game Easier

When playing on a touchscreen enabled device, you don't have any method to duck. To get around this, the game seems to reconfigure the flying down arrows to never be so low that you need to duck. This means that when playing on a touch enabled device, you are never forced to jump over a flying down arrow and can confidently walk underneath all of them.

### Touchscreen Loophole

If you're using a tablet with a keyboard, you can be in this easier game configuration while still using the keyboard controls.

If you scroll your window down or cover the top half of the game with a piece of paper so that you don't see the flying down arrows anymore, you can just focus on the hat obstacles. This way, you don't accidentally try to jump over any flying down arrows.

Comment: to be fair, it seems that the game has a "bug-feature-by-design" when compared to the original version: by Yaakow own comment, ducking doesn't seem to work to avoid "low" flying things. So, while it may be true that you don't get low arrows on mobile - never tested myself - you may want to add that ducking ***doesn't work in the first place and will just end up getting you killed.***

Comment: Ducking seems to have worked for me? Maybe it's all been psychological though, huh. I'll have to see!

Comment: Tried multiple times, always died. And [this exchange on chat seems to confirm it](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/117306?m=56448438#56448438)

Comment: I've been messing around with it as well, would like to confirm that, at least from my time playing so far. Obstacles are either so grounded that they can't be ducked under, or in the air enough that you can walk under, so there will never be an obstacle that you can duck under that you can't also just walk under. It is worth noting that the obstacles that you normally walk under can be jumped over with some more precise spacing starting at around 900 score.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @kylejrp's answer...

**If you play Hat Dash on a touch screen, remember to flip your phone horizontally**

When playing on a phone vertically like > , it's hard to see what's in front of you.

When playing horizontally, you can see much more things in front of you, it's much easier than playing vertically.

Answer (score 1):

Since a jump is either ended once max height is reached or when spacebar/up arrow is released, it's good to adapt accordingly based on your speed.

- If it's low, then you should release the key only after the max height is reached so that the jump will last longer. This is useful when you come across some big piles of hats at the beginning of the game.
- If it's high, then press space/up arrow and release it immediately to make a short jump and avoid losing by hitting an obstacle before landing (alternative of [kylejrp's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/358099)).