# Link directly to the "More information on cheating mechanisms" post from Hat Dash leaderboard

Tags: feature-request, winter-bash-2020, hat-dash

Over at the [Hat Dash leaderboard](https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/hat-dash/leaderboard), the white `?` contains the tl;dr for the anti-cheat mechanisms, but the "More info" link just leads to Meta's homepage:

[image]

Maybe we could change that link to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358546/hat-dash-white-hat-hall-of-fame-and-leaderboard-refresh) post, where the details are actually given?