# What else is required from me to earn the "Defender of the Unicorn" hat?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2020, secret-hats, hat-dash

I managed to get an illegitimate score into the top of the leaderboard while circumventing the updated auto-ban system, and I reported [how it was done](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/358855/278479). Unless there exists additional criteria that I'm unaware of, I believe that I've met the existing criteria to earn this hat.

So my first question is, **what else is required of me to earn this hat?**

I was also mysteriously banned sometime after my post. I suspect that I was manually banned because at no point after my post did I trip the auto-ban system.

So my second question is, **why was I banned?**

**I'm well aware that this hat is manually awarded. I'm not asking, why haven't I received it yet? I'm simply asking if any further action is required from my part.**

Here are some examples of what an acceptable answer to my first question should look like:

**Nothing else is required from you.**

Or

**Hey your post is missing X, Y and Z.**

Answer (score 16):

Nothing else is needed from you. Required: for me to either no longer be on vacation, or for me to take time from my vacation to evaluate new HOF entrants and award the hat.

> noble attribute
> oft preached, harder to practice
> oh vaunted patience

You were banned from the leaderboard for cheating.

Comment: So how exactly did you arrive at the conclusion that I lack patience? Is an inquiry equivalent to rushing the process?

Comment: I did not mean that you lacked patience per se. Just that you would need it in order to wait for me to get back from vacation and go through the new answers. I changed the wording here to remove the implication. Hopefully we can consider this issue closed now.

Comment: Case closed. Thank you.