# Leaderboard on Hat Dash showing triplicates?

Tags: bug, winter-bash-2020, data-analysis, hat-dash, duplication

When I was looking at the 'Overall Statistics' section of the hat dash leaderboard, for the entire winter bash, I came across the following:
[image]

I am pretty sure this is an error, as they all have the same user, score, and date, but what is causing this to happen, and why? (Also, it is mathematically impossible for the same user to have three games of over 300 seconds -- 5 minutes each -- in the span of one minute. Unless there was a source code running on three different browsers/windows/tabs at the same time, causing all the games to finish at the exact same time with the exact same score.)

I did not encounter this problem with any of the other leaderboards, so I believe that it might be case specific.

Hat dash leaderboard linked here:
[Hat dash leaderboard](https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/hat-dash/leaderboard)

I am just curious to why this is happening. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: SE knows @double-beep don't mess around. That's why he's top 3 at NO#1.

Comment: See the hat? It means the user took part in "hacking" the game, so when Yaakov cleaned up the mess, there were some leftovers. :-)

Comment: Also, the user should now rename to triple-beep.

Comment: @ShadowtheHatterWizard I agree, but even if Yaakov left some stuff remaining, wasn't the point of the anti-cheat/hack code... well to be able to figure and take out stuff like that?

Comment: @JoeKerr no. it was for blocking such things; cleanup is different, less important, matter. I don't argue it's a bug; Just giving the possible cause. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I've mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/358187) (<s>plz send teh upvotez</s>), two requests were done (before the most recent anti-cheating heuristics), one to `/hat-dash/start` and one to `/hat-dash/end`.

During my initial testing, I made a request to `/hat-dash/start` with `startedAt` set to `new Date().getTime()`. Then, I made three `/hat-dash/end` requests using the same `startedAt` (which was stored in a variable) and score, yet because I had set the duration to `new Date().getTime() - startedAt`, it kept changing and that's why you see me three times in the leaderboard.