# Can a user play Winter Bash Unicorn game without being a member of any Stack Exchange(or SO) site?

Tags: bug, winter-bash, winterbash-leaderboard

I opened the leaderboard link provided in this [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358564/leaderboard-on-hat-dash-showing-triplicates).

At the top of the Leaderboard, there is a user with username **joblessperson**.

[image]

I opened their Network Profile, but saw they aren't a member of SO or any SE site. The other tabs are also empty.

[image]

How is this possible? We should be a member of at least one SE (or SO) community to earn the privilege to play the Winter Bash game.

[Here](https://stackexchange.com/users/19593967/joblessperson?tab=accounts) is their profile link.

Comment: Not sure if this is an answer, so I'm putting it in a comment. When that score first showed up, the user in question (joblessperson) had a profile picture attached to to their score, which now appears to be gone. This indicates to me that at one point, when the score was first put there, they had an account on at least one SE page - though it may now be gone.

Comment: Perhaps they've just hidden all the sites they are a member of.

Comment: Even their activity tab is empty.

Comment: @CollinB But I think in that case, their account name should also have.

Comment: I'd offer to help test by deleting my account, but for obvious reasons I'm a little tentative to offer :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There used to be such a user: (Google cache from November 3<sup>rd</sup> 2020)

[image: answer by the user]

However this now leads to 404 Not Found which means the account has been deleted.

So most likely the user did have account while playing Hat Dash, and deleted it only later.

Comment: Thanks! I should have spent some more time to search whether there was such user..