# Hat Dash scoreboard/scoring flaw?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, winter-bash-2020, unicorns, hat-dash

A very simple, yet addictive game... but is anyone else noticing that their scores aren't being recorded? My highest score overall is 2,543 (December 17th) which should put me at 15th (as of December 26th) in the overall stats but I don't appear there at all. Also today (about 30 mins ago) I got a score of 2,345 which should put me at 23rd in overall and also appearing in today's stats but I still don't appear anywhere even after refreshing the page multiple times...

Comment: I can reproduce... I could've sworn I got nearly 2000 points today but now such score isn't appearing anywhere.

Comment: Hat Dash has *aggressive* anti-cheating heuristics. If the system deems your score as suspiciously high, then it will not show up in the public leaderboard. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358104/do-you-see-a-way-to-cheat-at-hat-dash and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358546/hat-dash-white-hat-hall-of-fame-and-leaderboard-refresh

Comment: @CodyGray right, totally agree with anti-cheating protocols but the thing is my scores definitely aren't suspiciously high...