# Are diamond moderators exempted from the minimum duration of bounties (1 day)?

Tags: support, bounties, moderator-tools, moderators

During the recent Winter Bash, Yaakov ["solicited help on finding ways to prevent (or at least make it harder) for folks to cheat at Hat Dash"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358546/hat-dash-white-hat-hall-of-fame-and-leaderboard-refresh) and awarded successful users with a bounty.

The bounties were awarded to all the qualifying users in quick succession, giving us the following [impressive timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/358104/timeline):

> [image]
>
> Timeline for [Do you see a way to cheat at Hat Dash?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358104/do-you-see-a-way-to-cheat-at-hat-dash)

From the [help centre article on bounties](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/bounty):

> Bounties must have a minimum duration of at least 1 day.

This brings me to my question: Are diamond moderators exempted from the minimum duration of bounties (1 day)?

Comment: Evidently they were also exempt from the normal rule that successive bounties from the same user on the same post must be at least double the previous one, as the revisions page shows: there were several successive bounties worth 50 rep, whereas a normal user would have been limited to first 50, then 100, then 200, then 400, then 500 (the max) for each one thereafter.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yaakov altered the code to add an exemption from all bounty rules for staff only, after realizing how difficult and time consuming it'd be to fulfill that bounty promise.

It was made a site setting so it could be turned back off because it's not meant to be a permanent "staff can ignore the rules" thing. It is currently only enabled here on Meta because he needed it for that specific post. Supposedly it will be disabled again at some point.

It is not available to diamond moderators at all.

Comment: We can confirm that [promising bounties on a contest](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349555/a-yaakov-ellis-inspired-meta-se-poetry-contest-write-poems-win-rep) does require some bureaucratic overhead, coordination, stamina and dedication to get it all award fairly and within the system design limits. Kudos to Yaakov again for making it all work for us and for him.

Comment: I don't see a big issue with leaving it enabled on this Meta site. I would have issues with it being used on other sites, of course.