# The Rescue of The Winter Unicorn Of The Bash

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, fun, unicorns, winter-bash-2021

One year had passed since their last meeting and the yellow pony was waiting near the pool for the unicorn to appear again. Long they waited, playing with the snow on-off switch. Winter, Summer, Hot, Cold, Ice, Water... Seconds become minutes and minutes became hours.

But the *unicorn* didn't come this time.

Fearing that something bad had happened, the yellow pony frantically started looking for clues. They tried asking the chicken if she noticed anything, but the hen was empty saved for a lone old tape player stuck playing an annoying song. They rushed to the deer only to find he was gone too. The pig, the little cat, the crocodile... all of them.

The forest was empty. And everywhere a single tape player was left in their place, playing the same cursed melody.

The pony was starting to panic when they decided to look in the only place left. *The spot they first meet some years ago*.

Here the yellow pony found a scrap of paper, *with some random characters scribbled on it*. They closed their eyes, thinking, *decoding* the pieces of info they had before finally knowing what happened.

"Wait for me" they said as they rushed in the distance. "I'll save you".

*Stay tuned...*

---

Disclaimer: this post is made to raise awareness about a little "extra" event while leaving to the players the pleasure to work out the thing themselves. Further edits will be made as more info become available.

Comment: Who knows? Maybe it will come lol

Comment: Seems as though Sparkles has been kidnapped - who would do such a thing??

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the event it refers to is no longer available but the question should remain for historical value.

Comment: @Rob ... do you realize this post is about the **2021**  event right? **It is already a year later**...

Comment: That is completely addressed in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similarly to what happened last year, the new event is now live.
For further details, please refer to Yaakov post [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374461/oh-no-can-you-find-our-unicorn)

Answer (score 4):

There is a Defender of the Unicorn hat!!!

Yaakov just got it.

And there is a page (no spoiling):

<Redacted by Yaakov, in order to ensure security for the unicorn>

Comment: There's an HTML comment with a link to previous year's post:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/358638/51

Comment: just for reference, it is currently unclear if this game will award the Defender hat too. The current only active trigger is another one. Yet, if this plays out like it did last year, we may get some quiz/small game next week for another alternate way to get the hat.

Comment: The page is still on hold. I guess Yaakov will update it when he returns next Friday. You may want to point this out  maybe.