# Will the "Defender of the Unicorn" hat lead to lots of pointless noise in meta?

Tags: bug, winter-bash, winter-bash-2022

Obviously I’m asking this because as I’m seeking the "Defender of the Unicorn" hat but it also raises the question, are hats like this just going to end up causing extra noise in the meta site (like this one)?

It’s a stretch I know, but if you could just tag this [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) it would be appreciated.

Looks like all the bugs have been ironed out, so how are you legitimately meant to earn this hat?

Comment: Love the down-votes. If this isn’t the approach what do you suggest instead? I could go and try and hunt down some obscure bug in the [tag:winter-bash] that needs addressing but I imagine most of them have already be raised. Open to suggestions…

Comment: Downvoted because I see no purpose for this question, apart from generating the very noise you seem to be concerned about. Also, why ask for the [status-completed] tag if there is nothing to which that status can be applied, let alone be discussed?

Comment: @Joachim That was a whole point…but at the same time I tried to make it relevant. I’m not sure other then trying to identify bugs in the [tag:winter-bash] how you can legitimately earn this hat.

Comment: @Joachim You don’t see the purpose? I’m fairly sure the purpose is [pretty obvious](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384709/202529).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No. Most Winter Bash participants know better than to post pointless noise in search of hats, and the few who do usually get downvoted quickly and end up with a question ban or give up themselves. The moderator team is ready to handle any escalations but I haven't seen any (both this year and last year).

It helps that most contributions for a hat need to be *well-received*, i.e. have a positive score. IIRC the hat you mention is awarded manually, but even if it were automatic, I'm pretty sure the developers would include `Score > 0` in the query.

Comment: I guess that’s why many setup chat rooms to get the chat related hats specifically but each to their own.

Comment: Okay, so what legitimate way would you suggest?

Comment: There's (usually) a second way to get the hat, some kind of easter egg game. Stay tuned ...

Comment: Usually? Second way? I don't remember even one single secret hat ever with several different ways to get it, so don't really understand what you mean by your comment.

Comment: @Shadow https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374461/oh-no-can-you-find-our-unicorn https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358638/can-you-help-a-poor-unicorn-to-find-its-way-back-home

Comment: @Glorfindel oh, that. This year a new (to winter bash) developer is working on it, so no such game. All attempts lead to rick roll on YouTube without any hint or exception. Funny, but we're not going to get any further fun or hat from it.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars: Don't be so sure...