# The Oldie Astley List of Rolls

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, unicorns, easter-eggs, winter-bash-2022

... Also known as "How many rolls must a staff member put down Before you call him a man" (obviously, the answer is 42).

As for tradition ([1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304391/the-quest-for-the-winter-chicken-of-the-bash-part-2), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319928/the-lord-of-the-hats-the-return-of-the-chicken), [3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357976/winter-bash-2020-the-return-of-the-unicorn) ) the pony went once again to visit their animal friends, hoping any of them would have some interesting tale to tell.

They would not find no tale this year, yet they immediately realized something was wrong. The ancient lord of pranks Allejo had put a curse on all their friends, and now everyone was singing an old, irritating song.

"Oh, this is terrible! I must find a way to put a stop to this" the pony said. But they had no idea as where to start. So, they asked to their purple, book loving old friend.

And, quite unsurprising, the purple one proposed they started with a list. "Maybe there is an hidden pattern" she said as she started writing down what every animal was singing...

"**[For Christmas our pranking dev gave to me](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Twelve_Days_of_Christmas_(song))**"

- [12 flapping](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mTXzFkYX7-g)
- [11 burninating](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mTXzFkYX7-g)
- [10 grazing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cErgMJSgpv0)
- [9 oinking](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=prZBPTfcrbA)
- [8 sliding](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cvh0nX08nRw)
- [7 moderating](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mTXzFkYX7-g)
- [6 running](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=prZBPTfcrbA)
- [5 bug-finding](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IdkCEioCp24&t=90s)
- [4 golden scaled , pouring the Nile water](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ)
- [3 sled pulling](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cErgMJSgpv0)
- [2 candy colored](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F5-BAYPoqdY)[image]
- [1 returning](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E8gmARGvPlI)

---

**Disclaimer**: many (but not ***ALL***) of the triggers are actually random. The list should only be seen as a reference that hopefully most will know, you may get different results for each animal. If you find a link that I don't listed, please leave me a notice and I will add it.

Comment: You forgot cat.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars 6 bug-finding ...... and hopefully you get WHY the cat is a bug-finder...

Comment: lol that does not look like a cat, by far. But Chrome's fault, not yours. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars and you evaded my question :P

Comment: Sad no panda 

Comment: Should that be "burninating"?

Comment: @Joachim you are right, thanks.